# MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: There is no 'root'@'%' registered

Tags: mysql, root

i run web application on iis 6 , windows server 2003 , mysql database.

first it was working fine, but when i reconfigured the mysql server with the same password it gave me this message error when i want to enter any page in browser :

```
"MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: There is no 'root'@'%' registered".
```

i checked the app connection it's the same, as though the app doesn't see the localhost , because "dbforge" sometimes give me this message: `"connection localhost cannot be found"` but when i doubleclick the connection it opens as root.

any idea to solve this problem

---

i solve it :

to access mysql from any pc you'd have to issue the following command...

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON . TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mysql' WITH GRANT OPTION;

Comment: sounds to me that ur app doesn't have the rights to connect to the db... double check the user,password and host

Comment: the web app is on the same machine as the mysql server?

Comment: yes, they are on the same machine

Comment: as the host try using instead of `localhost` the ip `127.0.0.1` also execute this: `select `Host`, `User` from mysql.user` and see if you have a entry for `root,localhost`

Comment: i tried : 127.0.0.1 nothing changed.
mysql> select user(); | root@localhost

Comment: that's the current user which is irrelevant ... you need to see the output of `select Host, User from mysql.user`

Comment: thank you , i solve it by adding privileges to root user